# Trouble running `stack ghci` when calling C++ from Haskell

Tags: c++, haskell, ghc, ghci, haskell-stack

**What I'm trying to do:** I am trying to call C++ (via an `extern "C" { ... }` interface) from Haskell via its FFI. In particular, I have a C++ file `three.cpp`; inside it is a single externed C++ function that I am trying to access from Haskell (with some other private C++ code in the background).

**The Problem:** I can successfully run `stack build` and `stack test` and everything works as expected. However, when I run `stack ghci` I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home//Dropbox/Sling/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/Sling-exe/Sling-exe-tmp/src/three.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

**Possibly Needed Information:** The relevant portion of my project's `.cabal` file looks as follows:

```
executable Sling-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -fPIC -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N 
  cc-options:          -fPIC
  extra-libraries:     stdc++
  build-depends:       base
  C-sources:           src/three.cpp
  Include-dirs:        include
  Includes:            include/three.h
  Install-includes:    three.h
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Notice how I tried to include the `-fPIC` flag, but failed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue turns out that *ALL* non-pure C code (i.e., strict C++ code) must be surrounded by #ifdefs:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus //I wasn't surrounding pure C++ code with these headers!
extern "C" {         
#endif

void foo();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```